# Trying to install OCaml 3.12.1 on Linux with Godi

Tags: ocaml, godi

I'm trying to install OCaml 3.12.1 on 64 bit Linux (Mint Linux which is essentially Ubuntu 11.04).  I'm using the latest rocketboost (godi-rocketboost-20110717).  I run ./bootstrap and after a while get the following (in bootstrap.log):

> 4287 ### Building godi-pcre
>
> 4288 ===> Cleaning for godi-pcre-6.2.2godi1
>
> 4289 => Checksum mismatch for pcre-ocaml-6.2.2.tar.gz.
>
> 4290 Make sure the Makefile and checksum file (/home/phil/godi-3.12.1/build/godi/     godi-pcre/distinfo)
>
> 4291 are up to date.  If you want to override this check, type
>
> 4292 "godi_make NO_CHECKSUM=yes [other args]".
>
> 4293 Error: Exec error: File /home/phil/godi-3.12.1/build/godi/godi-pcre/./../../     mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1689: Command returned with non-zero exit code
>
> 4294 Error: Command fails with code 1: godi_console

Is this a package problem with pcre?

And how would I use the suggest "godi_make NO_CHECKSUM=yes [other args]" to fix this?

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with the package when it was generated.  Supposed to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by the maintainer of the pcre-ocaml library. It should work fine now.